# Определить большую из 4 переменных

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Есть 4 переменные, нужно определить, какая из них самая большая и вернуть имя переменной. Мне пришел в голову только такой метод, но он мне не нравится. Возможно есть более изящный способ?

```
var Kas1 = 200;
var Kas2 = 300;
var Kas3 = 50;
var Kas4 = 205;
var Max = Math.max(Kas1, Kas2, Kas3, Kas4);
if (Kas1 == Max) { var MaxKas = "Kas1"; }
if (Kas2 == Max) { var MaxKas = "Kas2"; }
if (Kas3 == Max) { var MaxKas = "Kas3"; }
if (Kas4 == Max) { var MaxKas = "Kas4"; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для таких операций используют структуры, в которых можно хранить однородные данные.

Важно. Не уверен, что вы можете гарантировать, что максимум может быть только один, поэтому результатом поиска будет массив.

Базовый вариант - хранение в массивах:

```js
const data = [200, 300, 50, 205];
const names = ['kas1', 'kas2', 'kas3', 'kas4'];

const max = Math.max(...data);

const result = names.filter((_, i) => data[i] === max);

console.log(result);
```

Но скорее всего, вы придете к тому, к чему и все - использованию объектов, как минимально необходимой для описания единицы какой-либо сущности:

```js
const kasses = [{
    name: 'kas1',
    val: 200,
  },
  {
    name: 'kas2',
    val: 300,
  },
  {
    name: 'kas3',
    val: 50,
  },
  {
    name: 'kas4',
    val: 205,
  },
];

const max = Math.max(...kasses.map((item) => item.val));

const result = kasses.filter((item) => item.val === max);

console.log(result);
console.log(result.map(k => k.name));
```